# How do I use "--args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security" in arc browser's google

Tags: arc-browser

like title say，How do I use "--args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security" command in arc browser's google，

I have tried to find some issues related to arc browser, but I don't seem to see any relevant answers so far